# Closing laptop lid freezes touchpad

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, lid

Laptop touchpad freezes if lid is closed. I observed this in Kubuntu 16.04, 18.04 and 18.10 fresh installs. Suspend/Hibernate causes no such issues. After a bit of search, I found some similar cases with accepted answers as removing/restarting modules (Ex: `rmmod psmouse; modprobe -r psmouse`). This does not work in my case. After closing lid, external mouse still works.
Drivers - *xserver-xorg-input-synaptics*
PS: *xserver-xorg-input-libinput* also has this issue. This comes with the fresh install. I prefer using synaptics driver unless there is a strong reason against it as it provides lot of customization. Tried having both together but still no use.

Output of `dmesg | grep -iE "synaptics|psmouse"` before closing lid

```
[    2.378635] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried max coordinates: x [..5656], y [..4712]
[    2.418825] psmouse serio1: synaptics: queried min coordinates: x [1326..], y [1200..]
[    2.418834] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Your touchpad (PNP: SYN1ef2 SYN1e00 SYN0002 PNP0f13) says it can support a different bus. If i2c-hid and hid-rmi are not used, you might want to try setting psmouse.synaptics_intertouch to 1 and report this to linux-input@vger.kernel.org.
[    2.494387] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x12e800/0x0, board id: 2997, fw id: 1665536
[    2.543428] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
```

`cat /dev/input/mice` still prints characters after closing the lid.

How to fix this or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue on Kubuntu 22.04.2 LTS with a Synaptics Touchpad on an HP laptop.  I have not found a way to prevent it from happening, but if you install the Synaptics drivers (sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics) and restart your session, in the GUI you can go to System Settings > Hardware > Input Devices > Touchpad > Enable/Disable Touchpad (Tab) > Keyboard Shortcuts (Configure Button) > Enable/Disable Touchpad > Enable Touchpad and click the "custom" button to set up a hotkey to enable the touchpad.  I chose ALT+T, and it works great!